# Why the time not working in the code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a random image code but the time intrvel is not working on the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //extending jQuery with ':random' selector, best put into separate plugin js file
    jQuery.jQueryRandom = 0;
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[":"],
    {
        random: function(a, i, m, r) {
            if (i == 0) {
                jQuery.jQueryRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length);
            };
            return i == jQuery.jQueryRandom;
        }
    });        
    //end :random extend
$ (Function () { 
    var next = function ()
    {

    . $ ('# Slideshow img') not (': random') hide (). 
    setInterval (function () {
        $ ('# Slideshow img: visible') fadeOut ('slow').
        . Siblings ('img: random'). FadeIn ('slow')

    }, 10000);
    }
    next ();
    });
</script>
```

That "10000" is not working.Please help me

Comment: Is it editing error or your coding error?

Comment: sorry . I don't know . I am new in jqaury , this code got from a site

Comment: `google` cant do this

Comment: How about taking some **[jQuery Tutorials](http://learn.jquery.com/)** ?

Comment: i updated the code.Please help somebody. Its very urgent issue me

Comment: Is there any alternate methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

```
setInterval(function(){
randNum = getRandomInt(0, imgArray.length - 1);
nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[randNum] + ") no-repeat bottom center";
$('#slideshow img:first').attr("src", imgArray[randNum]);
```

}, 10000);